# So I've been Googling function arguments and I would like to understand arguments better and the use of ()

Tags: actionscript-3, function, arguments

So I've been Googling function arguments and I would like to understand arguments better.

I am new to as3, to summarize arguments with my current knowledge, I would say they are like temporary variables? I don't fully get why you add parameters which are names that can be any value? Then you like call these parameters later and their order magically replace these parameters, but why? I'm missing some understanding here to fully grasp their use. Why make parameters in a function and then add the values later? If I'm even saying that right.

```
function name( applepie, sugar, healthyfood)

name( 1,2,3)
```

What was the point?

Also I haven't found a syntax book that describes what every symbol does yet that I can just search like () and it describes it, I heard some just use Google, but the results I got weren't very fruitful. Hence why I'm here asking. Personally I don't want to continue on until I fully grasps the use of (). I also tried Adobe website search but that didn't work out well either, was a good amount of searches trust me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is a piece of code that can be reused many times in different contexts.  You pass arguments to a function to tell the function something about the context in which it is being called; as a trivial example, when you call the print() function you must specify what you want the function to print.  In your example name(applepie, sugar, healthyfood) the function should use the value supplied in place of each argument somewhere in its body, because the function doesn't know what values it will be passed, in the body of the function definition you use the names you chose (which should be descriptive) to refer to the values which will be passed in later and which will presumably be different each time it is called.

The parentheses are used for delimiting different semantic elements, in this case they are telling the interpreter where the argument list starts and stops.